# Customised sorting of elements in an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have heard of sorting techniques like quicksort, bubblesort, mergesort and many others. I have an array like

```
arr[]={2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 5, 1, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3}
```

Using bubble sort I can get the sorting done as

```
arr[]={1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}
```

But I need to sort the given array in this manner

```
arr[]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 1, 1, 2, 3 )
```

That is, any re-occurances of values need to be moved to end of the array.

My idea is to bubblesort the array first and then using this sorted array, traverse through the array moving any repeated occurrences to end of the array.

Can it be done this way? If yes, what will be the algorithm after getting bubble sorted array.
Or is there a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Do the recurring values need to be sorted?

Comment: Yes, the array could be anything. First occurrences as well as recurring values also need to be sorted, like if my array is a[]={4,5,6,1,1,3,3,4,4,4,1,9,9,8,8}. Resultant array needs to be a[]= {1,3,4,5,6,8,9,1,1,3,4,4,4,8,9}

Answer (score 1):

You can conduct bubble sort in two passes.

In the first pass, find the smallest element and put it in the first place. Then find the element that is **greater** than the last element found but smallest from among the lot and put it in second place.

Do the above till you reach the maximum element.

Once you reach the maximum element, bubble sort on the remaining part of the array normally.

Order of complexity: Exactly as per Bubble sort, since you are just dividing it in two halves.

Full working code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 5, 1, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3};
    int size = 12;
    // find max element.
    int max = -1;
    for ( int I = 0; I < size; I++ ) {
      if ( arr[I] > max )
        max = arr[I];
    }


    int begin = 0;
    bool maxPlaced = false;
    int lastFound = -1;
    while ( !maxPlaced ) {

      // find the first element from the end,
      // that is greater than elements already placed.
      int end = size-1;
      while ( arr[end] <= lastFound )
          end--;

      for ( int I = end; I > begin; I-- ) {

        // swap if arr[i-1] is higher than arr[i]
        // or arr[i-1] is a number that we have already placed.
        if ( arr[I] < arr[I-1] || lastFound >= arr[I-1] ) {
            int temp = arr[I];
            arr[I] = arr[I-1];
            arr[I-1] = temp;
        }
      }
      // lastfound is the highest number that we have placed till now.
      lastFound = arr[begin];
      begin++;
      if ( lastFound == max )
        maxPlaced = true;

    }

    //continue bubble sort from begin position.
    for ( int I = begin; I < size; I++ ) {
      for ( int j = begin; j < size - 1 - (I-begin); j++ ) {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 2 3
```

For input of `{4,5,6,1,1,3,3,4,4,4,1,9,9,8,8}`

Output:

```
1 3 4 5 6 8 9 1 1 3 4 4 4 8 9
```

Comment: Abhi,kudos for your proactive solution.

Comment: Thanks! code updated with comments.

Comment: Abhi,sometime I see a runtime error disturbing the execution flow. 'Process exited with return value 3277658738'

Comment: @Bala the code will need minor tweaks since it is just to give you an idea. Eg. It currently doesn't work for negative elements. If you find and specify the input array then it can be debugged. Also the size of array has been hard coded at present.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that bubble-sort is the least efficient sorting algorithm of those 3 you mentioned.
It's `O(n2)` average case while the others are `O(n log n)`.

**Heap-sort**

A variation on [heap-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_sort) comes to mind as an efficient (`O(n log n)`) way to do this.

- Build a heap of the items.
- Have a left and a right iterator into the array, pointing to the left-most and right-most positions respectively.
- While the heap is not empty:

  - Remove the maximum.
  - If the removed item is the same as the last removed item, insert it at the right iterator and decrease the iterator.
  - Otherwise insert it at the left iterator and increase the iterator.

Now if the items at the end need to be sorted as well, just reverse their order (they should be in reverse order at the end of the above process).

**In-place alternative - selection sort**

[Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) finds the maximum element at each step, so this can easily be modified to skip the applicable elements if they're greater than an already found element.

This can be done in-place (where the above can't), but is again `O(n2)`.

```
int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 5, 1, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3};
int arrLength = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
{
   int minPos = -1;
   for (int j = i; j < arrLength; j++)
      // either it's the first element, or it's greater than the last element
      //   and either it's the first such element we find, or smaller than the best one
      if ((i == 0 || arr[j] > arr[i-1]) && 
          (minPos == -1 || arr[j] < arr[minPos]))
      {
         minPos = j;
      }

   // no more elements to sort
   if (minPos == -1)
      break;

   int temp = arr[i];
   arr[i] = arr[minPos];
   arr[minPos] = temp;
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/0rGw3w).

If the repeated elements needs to be sorted as well, this will need to be done additionally (with any sort method).

Comment: Nice idea. Though I think you would require extra space for the heap as such a modified heap sort wouldn't be possible in place.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal True, I'm not sure in-place is a requirement here though. Added an in-place selection-sort approach to my answer.